# Django intermediate page and processing multiple items

Tags: django

i'm very new to python and Django and wanted to give it a try by building a web interface for my personnal media library.

I created a custom admin action that request TMDB API to store the movies information in my DB.

If there's multiple results for a movie, i redirected to an intermediate page with a ChoiceField() to select the appropriate one.

Here's the problem, when i validate the intermediate page it add my selection to the DB but stop processing the other requested movies...

I assume the problem is coming for the redirection after the form processing but i can't figure it.

Thanks for your help fellas !

admin.py

```
class MovieAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
actions = ['parse']
list_display = ['title', 'year', 'status']
change_list_template = "admin/movies_changelist.html"

def parse(self, request, queryset):
    if 'apply' in request.POST:
        form = MovieSelectForm(request.POST)
        res = ast.literal_eval(request.POST['res'])
        for r in res:
            if r['id'] == int(request.POST['Movies']):
                update_movie_infos(request.POST['_selected_action'], r)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.get_full_path())

    SELECTED_MOVIES = []
    for movie in queryset:
        if movie.status == 'UN':
            # Building API Request
            api_key = '8a260244852cbd90bc5662e721a2d685'
            uri = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie'
            req = requests.get(uri, {
                'api_key': api_key,
                'query': movie.title,
                'year': movie.year,
                'language': 'fr-FR'
            }).json()
            res = req['results']
            if len(res) == 1:
                update_movie_infos(movie.pk, res[0])
                self.message_user(
                    request, '{} parsed successfully.'.format(movie.title))
            elif len(res) == 0:
                self.message_user(request, '{}: no results.'.format(
                    movie.title), level='error')
            else:
                self.message_user(
                    request, '{}: Please choose the movie corresponding.'.format(movie.title), level='warning')
                for r in res:
                    SELECTED_MOVIES.append((r['id'], r['title']))

                form = MovieSelectForm(SELECTED_MOVIES)
                return render(request, 'admin/TMDB_multiple_results.html', {
                    '_selected_action': queryset.values_list('pk', flat=True),
                    'entry': movie.pk,
                    'res': res,
                    'form': form
                })
```

Comment: your last two lines (`form = ...` and `return render(...)`) are incorrectly indented, they should be outside the for loop. As they are now, with the first pass of your for loop (the first `r`), you `return` so you never loop through the other movies.

Comment: I intended them but it's still not triggering the other items :/ Thanks anyway for pointing that out ;)

Comment: Then please edit your question to show the correct code as you have it in your source.

Comment: But this is still inside the `for movie in queryset` loop. Which doesn't make sense.

Comment: edit: it's triggering my intermediate  page but with all the results for all the movie as one big form. Is that the only way to do ?

Comment: You can't do this. You have to restrict people to only perform the action on one selection at a time. Return an error message if more than one is selected. There's no way to do what you want to do.

Comment: Ok, i see, thanks to for yyour time ;) Have a good day !

Comment: I mean you could organize your intermediate page to structure the choices per selected movie but that would require a formset (multiple forms), one for each selection with multiple movies and you would have to also somehow tell which ones are already processed. It gets complicated.